A frequentist understanding of the "multiplication rule"
Assume a uniform discrete setting. Let $A$ and $B$ be two events that depend on each other. I created this figure to assist me in visualizing the conditional universe

If the new conditional universe boils down two events with one contained in the other, I am having trouble trying to interpret the event $A\cap B$ in terms of $B\mid A$ from a frequency perspective.
For instance, I am able to interpret $\mathbb{P}(B\mid A)$ as
$$
\mathbb{P}(B\mid A)=\frac{|A\cap B|}{|A|}=\frac{|A\cap B|/|\Omega|}{|A|/|\Omega|}=\frac{\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)}{\mathbb{P}(A)}
$$
How can I try to establish the relation
$$
\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)=\mathbb{P}(B\mid A)\mathbb{P}(A)
$$
in a similar fashion?
Well, if we try to say that
$$
|A\cap B|=\mathbb{P}(B\mid A)|A|
$$
Then one interpretation would be that the events of $A$ and $B$ happening together despite their dependency, is nothing more than filtering the event $A$ through $\mathbb{P}(B\mid A)$, but then again this still is not intuitive of the idea of the multiplication rule, because we are not able to see what $B\mid A$ really means to $A\cap B$.

I'm not 100% clear on what you're asking, but it feels like the answer to your question might be "$\mathbb{P}(B|A)$ is the conditional probability of $B$ given $A$, that is, it is the percentage of objects in $A$ that are also in $B$."  Is that the sort of thing you're looking for?

@tabstop My question can be summarised as "how would you explain the multiplication rule to a person walking down the street" the issue I am facing is that to Interpret $A\cap B$ you have to Interpret $B\mid A$ as part of the formula, but $B\mid A$ internally depends on the definition of $A\cap B$

I don't think any interpretation of $A\cap B$ other than "the objects that are in both $A$ and $B$" is either necessary or desirable here? Going back to what $\mathbb{P}(B|A)$ means, it is the probability of drawing a member of $B$ given that you're restricted to drawing from $A$ (rather than the universe $\Omega$), so saying "$\mathbb{P}(B|A) = 0.4$ means 40% of the objects in $A$ are also in $B$" would get you straight to that cardinality-multiplication expression.

(Or maybe to put it another way, both versions of the multiplication rule you've got here are just algebraic manipulations of each other, so using one to justify the other is probably always going to be circular; reach back to what conditional probability means to draw your explanation from.)

I totally agree that $A\cap B$ is seen as two events occurring together, but I am unable to understand how to equate it with the right hand side of the equation I wrote. Not by doing algebraic manipulation, but intuitively. @tabstop

$B \mid A$ is not an event in the original probability space, and so $\mathbb P(B \mid A)$ is not $\mathbb P(\cdot)$ where you put $B \mid A$ as the $\cdot$.  Instead you have $\mathbb P(\cdot \mid A)$ where you put $B$ as the $\cdot$.  If you change the probability space so that the sample space is $A$ instead of $\Omega$ (and consequential changes to the sigma-algebra of events and the measure), then $B$ and $A \cap B$ become the same event in that probability space.
